# Unable to implement jquery fileupload example from railscasts

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

I'm having no luck getting the ajax jquery fileupload working with my app, I'm basing my implementation off of Ryan Bate's, though I'm using Paperclip rather than Carrierwave http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload

In my console I'm getting the error: ReferenceError: file is not defined

Here's the backtrace from airbrake if it helps:

```
url/assets/styleitems.js?body=1:6 in "HTMLFormElement.$.fileupload.add"
url/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1:490 in "$.Widget._trigger"
url/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js?body=1:815 in "File.<anonymous>"
url/assets/jquery.js?body=1:385 in "Function.jQuery.extend.each"
url/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js?body=1:805 in "$.widget._onAdd"
url/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1:106 in "null._onAdd"
url/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.js?body=1:985 in "Object.<anonymous>"
url/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3100 in "fire"
url/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3146 in "Object.self.add"
url/assets/airbrake_shim.js?body=1:77 in "Object.cb.add"
```

In my application controller I have among other files:

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
```

I also have the jquery-fileupload-rails gem installed

js.coffee file:

```
 $ ->
  $('#new_styleitem').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
      $('#new_styleitem').append(data.context)
      data.submit()
    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

form:

```
= form_for([@class_object, Styleitem.new], html: {multipart: true}) do |f|
  = f.text_field :styleable_type, type: :hidden, value: @class_object.class.to_s
  = f.number_field :styleable_id, type: :hidden, value: @class_object.id
  = f.number_field :user_id, type: :hidden, value: authority_user.id
  = f.file_field :asset, multiple: true, name: "styleitem[asset]"
  = render partial: 'layouts/drag_and_drop'
```

contents of layouts/drag_and_drop

```
%script{id: "template-upload", type: "text/x-tmpl"}
  .upload
    .progress
      .bar{style: "width: 0%"}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, I was deleting some code from the coffeescript file that I wasn't using and I accidently removed

```
file = data.files[0]
```

Case closed.